# Uncaught TypeError: $.ee_filemanager.toggle_all is not a function

Tags: ee2, file-manager, bug, ee2.9.3

I encountered this bug in a clean install of EE2.9.3, using MSM.
I commented out the $.ee_filemanager.toggle_all in 'themes/compressed/cp/files/file_manager_home.js'.

Is this a bug? Or something I did wrong during installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug, and was fixed in 2.10: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20866/javascript-error-in-cp-file-manager